# Change image src by clicking on it -> to a src from the following thumbnail

Tags: jquery, html, image, src

I'm, tying to swap an image `src` from a main/single image by clicking on it to a `src` from the next following thumbnail.

```
<div id="productinfoleft">
  <img src="images/product_images/info_images/some_image_0.png" class="productimage">
  <div class="morepics">
    <div class="active">
      <img src="images/product_images/thumbnail_images/some_image_0.png">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="images/product_images/thumbnail_images/some_image_1.png">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="images/product_images/thumbnail_images/some_image_2.png">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="images/product_images/thumbnail_images/some_image_3.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By clicking on the thumbnails I can already swap the main image - so far so good. But on click on the main image I'd like to change the image to the next file of the following thumbnail pool. The jQuery code I use right now is:

```
// BOF PRODUCT-MORE-PICTURE CLICK SWAP
$('.morepics div:first').addClass('active');

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.morepics img').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.morepics div').removeClass('active');
    $('.productimage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumbnail_images/', 'info_images/'));
      $(this).parent('div').addClass('active');
    });

    var imgSwap = [];
    $('.morepics img').each(function() {
      imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumbnail_images/', 'info_images/');
      imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });
    $(imgSwap).preload();
  });

  $.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
      $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
  }

  // EOF PRODUCT-MORE-PICTURE CLICK SWAP
```

I have no clue how to change or extend my jQuery code to get this done also with a correct class change of the thumbnail div's to `active`. Any help would be really great - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the functionality for clicking on the actual thumbnails and updating the main image, i would just add some code on the main image that triggers a click on the next thumbnail (*using the `active` class already applied*).

Adding the following will do the trick

```js
/*load next image when clicking on productimage*/
$('.productimage').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thumbs = $('.morepics > div'), // get all wrapper divs of thumbnails
        active = thumbs.filter('.active'), // get the active div
        next = active.next(); // get the next div after the active

    if (!next.length) { // if active was the last, so not next exists, start from first
        next = thumbs.first();
    }

    next.find('img').trigger('click'); // trigger the existing handler of the img
});
```

Comment: Thank you "Gaby aka G. Petrioli" - **you made my day**!!! That's exactly what I needed.
Note: first it did not work as `.on('click', function ...` was not recognized. I noticed that I needed at last jQuery V 1.7 for this to work.
Next I will try to add some fadeIn fadeOut animation to it.

Comment: @bacelo Sorry about that. I always assume people use the latest versions or around that.

Comment: Maybe for someone also helpful in this case: regarding the fade transition on src change, I changed `$('.productimage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumbnail_images/', 'info_images/'))` to the following `$('.productimage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumbnail_images/', 'info_images/')).stop(true,true).hide().fadeIn("slow");`